# calling controller onclick in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

I am using spring web application,in jsp file i have to call controller in java file using ajax function,how could i call controller in java file from jsp file.

```
<p class="bottom-slide-corners">
                            <a class="billing" href="#Billing"><spring:message code="billing_area" /></a>
                        </p>


$('.billing').on('click', function(event) {
            clearSliderInterval();
            var $this = $(this);
            var $linkToFind = $($this.attr("href") + "_billing");
            var $slidesToFind = $("." + $this.attr("href").replace("#", "") + "_slide");

            if($this.parent().parent().siblings('.current-arrow').find('img').is(":visible")) {
                $this.parent().parent().siblings('.current-arrow').find('img:visible').slideUp();
                $('.Background').slideUp(function() {
                    $(".learn_more").hide();
                }).removeClass("open");
                return false;
            }

            if($window.width() <= 767) {
                $('#dashboard-mobile-banner, #header-bg, #footer-container, .container-slider').slideUp();

                var categoryClass = $linkToFind.attr('id').replace("learnMore", "slide");
                $('.courseDashboard').removeClass().addClass("courseDashboard Background " + categoryClass);
                $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
            }

            if($('.learn_more').is(":visible")) {
                $('.Background').slideUp(function() {
                    $('.learn_more').hide();
                    $linkToFind.show();
                    $('.Background').slideDown();
                });
            } else {
                $linkToFind.show();
                $('.Background').slideDown(function() {
                    if ($window.width() <= 767) {
                        var slider = $("#" + $linkToFind.attr('id') + " .thumbview").bxSlider({
                            slideWidth: 300,
                            pager: false
                        });
                        $('.close-panel:visible').on('click', function(e) {
                            slider.destroySlider();
                        });
                    }
                }).addClass("open");
            }

            $('.current-arrow img:visible').slideUp();
            $slidesToFind.find('.current-arrow img').slideDown();
            return false;
        });
```

here on click i want to call a controller in .java file,how could i call this below controller in jsp file code,on click

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/billing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String Billing(@RequestParam Long caseId,
            @RequestParam Long noteID, HttpServletRequest request)  throws Exception {
        try{

----------
            logger.debug("success ");
        return "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e,e);
            throw e;
        }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this ...it will 100% work :) .

```
(".billing").on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({url:"/billing", success: function(result){

    }});
})
```

Return your success string in map given by JSONObject , keep your key as "result"
and "success" as your String .Something like this you write in your controller

```
`JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
jsonObject1.put("result", "success");
String myResult= jsonObject1.toString();
response.getWriter().write(myResult);`
```

As you can see i have added `resp.getWriter()` . It sends response back to your controller. So also please add a response Object `HttpServletResponse resp` in your method public String Billing method like your have added `HttpServletRequest request`. Don't  add `return` statement in the Controller, and mark the controller method as `void`This will 100% work . Let me know if that helps !! :)

Comment: if i add this the design itself get changed and onclick controller is not getting called

Comment: What do u mean ? Please elaborate.

Comment: my controller in .java file is not returning json response,there is no need also as i need to do some updation to database in that controller,so what could i make it to return, as i am using ajax in jsp.if i return return JSONSerializer.toJSON(" ").toString();  it gives error   net.sf.json.JSONException: Invalid JSON String

Comment: as i currently see you are trying to return a success view , so if you want to return a json please tell me a json of what and have you changed code in your controller . If you have please paste the updated controller . Because all i can see in your current controller is that you are returning a view .

Comment: i dont want to return any thing from controller, as the method return type of controller  is string i am returning "Success".

Comment: i have added my response in my edited answer ! please check it . that will work.